# Find a process by name and kill it

Tags: linux, automation, process

So, I want to send a kill to a process, I know it's name

```
ps -ef | grep '_rails master'
root      2388     1  0 19:46 ?        00:00:04 unicorn_rails master -c /web/hero/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                   
root      2582  2172  0 20:28 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto _rails master
```

It is **unicorn_rails master [..]** how do I kill it?

I tried so far: *sed* and *expr*. But cant pass it as param to **kill**

Comment: Note that system services often come with start/stop scripts that do this work for you.  I have no idea but maybe this unicorn_rails might have something like that under /etc/init.d for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There exists a more direct command called pkill. Usage is as follows:

```
$ pkill "process name here"
```

Comment: also do `pkill -f 'unicorn_rails master'` if theres going to be multiple instances of the program running and you only want to kill that one

Answer (score 1):

You can the command:

```
$ sudo kill `pidof process_name`.
```

You can use also:

```
$ sudo killall process_name
```

If you want to use grep, you can try:

```
$ ps -ef | grep '_rails master' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $3}' | sudo kill
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
ps -ef | grep [u]nicorn_rails | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs kill
```

Note, the [] in 'grep [u]nicorn_rails' keeps you from matching on the grep command in the ps tree.